# a structure of compound related question

Tags: molecular-structure, noble-gases

Why the structure of XeF6 is capped octahedral but not pentagonal pyramidal although there is a possibility of being pentagonal pyramidal (with lone pair below the pyramid) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is because to minimize lone pair and bond pair repulsion. In pentagonal bipyramidal arrangement lone pair electron will occupy eqatorial position which results in more lone pair -bond pair repulsions.